# hector_slam tutorial errors

Tags: slam, navigation, rviz, hector-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When running the Hector_slam tutorial (http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_slam/Tutorials/MappingUsingLoggedData) using the downloaded .bag file I get a map, but I also get the following errors:

```
ERROR 1343506441.987975020, 1310297991.330406663: Trajectory Server: Transform from /map to scanmatcher_frame failed: Frame id /map does not exist! Frames (1):  
ERROR 1343506441.988524740, 1310297991.330406663: Trajectory Server: Transform from /map to scanmatcher_frame failed: Frame id /map does not exist! Frames (1):  
ERROR 1343506442.239030122, 1310297991.582959932: Trajectory Server: Transform from /map to scanmatcher_frame failed: Frame id /map does not exist! Frames (1):  
ERROR 1343506442.492759217, 1310297991.835439286: Trajectory Server: Transform from /map to scanmatcher_frame failed: Frame id /map does not exist! Frames (1):  
ERROR 1343506442.743658504, 1310297992.087936543: Trajectory Server: Transform from /map to scanmatcher_frame failed: Frame id /map does not exist! Frames (1):  
ERROR 1343506442.987813058, 1310297992.331234214: Trajectory Server: Transform from /map to scanmatcher_frame failed: Frame id /scanmatcher_frame does not exist! Frames (6):
Frame /base_link exists with parent /nav.
Frame /nav exists with parent /map.
Frame /base_stabilized exists with parent /nav.
Frame /base_footprint exists with parent /nav.
Frame /map exists with parent NO_PARENT.
```

And

```
SearchDir angle change too large
SearchDir angle change too large
```

What is needed here to correct this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40076/hector_slam-tutorial-errors/) by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on ROS Answers with karma: 160 on 2012-07-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The first one is a startup artifact that should go away as soon as the whole system is up and running. The trajectory server asks tf for the robot position with a fixed rate and directly at startup this might not yet be available. Should probably be changed to provide a warning instead of an error.

The second one is a hint that the scanmatcher did not converge correctly in two instances. This might happen at the beginning of the RoboCup2011 dataset due to me running around in the team area and shaking the mapping box too much. You should still get a consistent map at the end though.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TJump](https://answers.ros.org/users/2785/tjump/) on 2012-07-30**:
So verifying understanding, these errors are generated by the Hector_slam code (not ROS or Linux) and are a result of the data not available (from the bag file not yet running) at launch of the hector_slam tutorial? And yes, the second ones do not appear when running different bag files.

**Comment by [yza](https://answers.ros.org/users/11911/yza/) on 2014-02-12**:
If you get "hector_slam" package by "sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-hector-*", the first error may occur. I get the package by download the source code and run "catkin_make" myself, then source setup.bash in my workspace,  then run  "roslaunch XXX/hector_slam_launch/launch/tutorial.launch". Everything wil be okay that way:)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I also got the same errors and output except "SearchDir angle change too large" but in my case I don't get the map on RViz.

Does anybody know why the map doesn't appear?

---

Originally posted by [ebozgul](https://answers.ros.org/users/4340/ebozgul/) with karma: 11 on 2013-06-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1